Problem adding button to customtkinter image
I wanted to make a simple dhikrmatik (as the button is pressed, the number will increase and be written on the screen) application using customtkinter. I added a background image and wanted to add a button on the image, but the result was as in the picture. What is the solution? This article was written with Google Translate, I apologize if there is any mistake. thanks
enter image description here
from PIL import Image
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("systemTransparent")
root= customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("400x550")


my_image= customtkinter.CTkImage(
    dark_image=Image.open("zikirmat\image2.png"), 
    light_image=Image.open("zikirmat\image.png"),
    size=(300,300))


my_label =customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, width=30, height=35, image=my_image, text="")
my_label.place(x=50,y=5)

button =customtkinter.CTkButton(root,
                 text="",
                 width=110,
                 height=110,
                 corner_radius=100,
                 )
#button.configure(bg="white", alpha=0.5)  
button.place(y=180,x=100)



root.mainloop() 


I don't understand what is your problem. . What is wrong with button on image which you show on picture? We can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (not in comments)

use frames to enclose the image(background image and the label that will hold the values to be incremented every time the button is pressed, then have a function that will configure the label(increment it) every time the button is pressed
from PIL import Image
import customtkinter as ct

# Set appearance mode
ct.set_appearance_mode("systemTransparent")

# Create the main window
root = ct.CTk()
root.geometry("400x550")

# Load images
my_image = ct.CTkImage(
    dark_image=Image.open("seeit_1.jpg"),
    light_image=Image.open("seeit_2.jpg"),
    size=(300, 300)
)

# Create the label with initial value
count = 0
count_label = ct.CTkLabel(master=root, text=f"Count: {count}")
count_label.place(x=50, y=5)  # Adjust position if needed

# Function to increment the count and update the label
def increment_count():
    global count
    count += 1
    count_label.configure(text=f"Count: {count}")

# Create the button with the increment function linked
button = ct.CTkButton(
    master=root,
    text="Increment",
    width=110,
    height=110,
    corner_radius=100,
    command=increment_count  # Call increment_count on button click
)
button.place(y=180, x=100)  # Adjust position if needed

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()

